# PHP Generate day range

Tags: php, range, days

I am trying to generate the range of days, `from 1 to 28`, with the English ordinal suffix for the day of the month. For example: `1st of month`, `2nd of month`...

```php
for($i = 1; $i <= 28; $i++)
{
    $arrayRange[] = date('dS', strtotime($i));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayRange);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01st
    [1] => 01st
    [2] => 01st
    ...
    [26] => 01st
    [27] => 01st
)
```

What am I doing wrong..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it uses the contextual date functionality of '+1 day' etc to register your integer as a day :)

To answer your second question - as in what you're doing wrong - you're passing an integer to a [function that expects a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <= 27; $i++)
{
//The February is there to keep '1st' a '1st' even on days when it's not 
//the '31st'
$arrayRange[] = date('dS', strtotime("1st february +".$i.' day'));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayRange);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 01st
    [1] => 02nd
    ...
    [28] => 28th
)¨
```

Edit:
To remove the 0s, you can use ltrim() like this:

```
$arrayRange[$i] = ltrim(date('dS', strtotime("1st february +".$i.' day')), "0");
```

Which will give you an output like this

```
    [0] => 1st
    [1] => 2nd
    ...
    [28] => 28th
```

Edit 2:
Fixed it. Props to [MLF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1949062/mlf) for noticing the mistake.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer because it adds `$i` days to current day and because today is the last day of month, it makes correct results, but if you run it on another day, it won't start from `1st`.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it. Tested it in the NZ timezone, 1st is still the 1st, even on the 2nd :)

Comment: OK. I see you've edited your post to add "1st february" prefix. Now it's OK.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass correct timestamp as the second parameter of date function and use `j` (without leading zero) day format:

```
list($m, $y) = explode('-', date('m-Y'));
for($d = 1; $d <= 28; $d++)
{
    $arrayRange[] = date('jS', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayRange);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$arrayRange[] = (new DateTime('Aug '.$i))->format('jS');
```

Comment: $arrayRange = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 28; $i++) {
    $arrayRange[] = (new DateTime('Aug '.$i))->format('jS');
}
print_r($arrayRange);